# GWT KeyUpEvent not working on the server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I have such code on GWT:

```
  @UiHandler("playerSearchTextBox")
  public void onSearchPlayers(KeyUpEvent event) {
    String searchText = playerSearchTextBox.getText();
    GWT.log("search text :: " + searchText);
    List<Profile> players = new ArrayList<Profile>();
    for (Profile profile : originalPlayerList) {
      if (profile.getPlayerName().toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())) {
        players.add(profile);
        GWT.log("PLAYER :: " + profile);
      }
    }

    playersCellList.setRowCount(0);
    playersCellList.setRowData(players);

    GWT.log("players :: " + players);
  }
```

But seems it isn't calling on production server when I type also it works in development. I use SDM. I found answer that KeyUpEvent isn't cross-browser also I know that it worked some time ago.

Any workarounds?

**UPD**

I use GAE as production server.

**UPD 2**

There is generated js:

```
function $onSearchPlayers(this$static){
  var players, profile, profile$iterator, searchText, stackIndex;
  $stack_0[stackIndex = ++$stackDepth_0] = $onSearchPlayers;
  searchText = $getText_0(($location_0[stackIndex] = 'CheckersViewImpl.java:' + '119' , this$static).playerSearchTextBox);
  players = ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'CheckersViewImpl.java:' + '121' , new ArrayList);
  for ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'CheckersViewImpl.java:' + '122' , profile$iterator = new ArrayList$1(($tmp = ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'CheckersViewImpl.java:' + '122' , this$static).originalPlayerList , $location_0[stackIndex] = 'ArrayList.java:' + '141' , $tmp)); ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'ArrayList.java:' + '146' , ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'CheckersViewImpl.java:' + '122' , profile$iterator).i) < ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'ArrayList.java:' + '146' , ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'CheckersViewImpl.java:' + '122' , profile$iterator).this$01).array.length;) {
    profile = castTo($next_7(($location_0[stackIndex] = 'CheckersViewImpl.java:' + '122' , profile$iterator)), 108);
    indexOf_1(toLowerCase(($tmp = ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'Profile.java:' + '107' , ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'CheckersViewImpl.java:' + '123' , profile).playerName) , $location_0[stackIndex] = 'String.java:' + '738' , $tmp)), ($tmp = ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'String.java:' + '741' , $clinit_String() , ($tmp = ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'CheckersViewImpl.java:' + '123' , searchText) , $location_0[stackIndex] = 'String.java:' + '742' , $tmp).toLowerCase()) , $location_0[stackIndex] = 'String.java:' + '450' , $tmp)) != -1 && ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'ArrayList.java:' + '77' , ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'ArrayList.java:' + '77' , ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'CheckersViewImpl.java:' + '124' , players).array)[($location_0[stackIndex] = 'ArrayList.java:' + '77' , ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'CheckersViewImpl.java:' + '124' , players).array).length] = ($location_0[stackIndex] = 'CheckersViewImpl.java:' + '124' , profile));
  }
  $setRowCount(($location_0[stackIndex] = 'CheckersViewImpl.java:' + '129' , this$static).playersCellList, 0);
  $setRowData(($location_0[stackIndex] = 'CheckersViewImpl.java:' + '130' , this$static).playersCellList, players);
  $stackDepth_0 = stackIndex - 1;
}
```

Comment: GWT.log only works in development.  You need to be more specific when you say "not working".

Comment: I suggest it isn't callable because the players list didn't update. Nothing happens in production when I type but it works in dev mode.

Comment: So, what errors do you see in the browser dev tools?

Comment: I see log output and filtered player list. And, I don't see anything in production neither logs nor filtered player list.

Comment: Again, what do you see in browser dev tools in production?

Comment: Could you try KeyPressEvent?

Comment: No changes with KeyPress, KeyUp and KeyDown event. I've added generated pretty js in question.